# How to merge TFS change sets programmatically?

Tags: tfs, merge, changeset

I know how to merge a change set in TFS 2010 using the command line command "tf merge".

Is there a way I can do this in C# with code. I want to merge specific change sets only (cherry pick), one at a time.

Answer (score 8):

This is roughly how you would do it if you were working with the 2010 or 2012 TFS object models.  Let me know if you have any questions.

```
// Get a reference to yourTeam Foundation Server. 
TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://<yourserver>:8080/tfs/<yourcollection> "));

// Get a reference to Version Control. 
VersionControlServer versionControl = tpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

Workspace workspace = versionControl.GetWorkspace("<local path to your workspace>");

string sourceBranch = "$/<sourceBranch>";
string targetBranch = "$/<targetBranch>";
VersionSpec changesetToMerge = new ChangesetVersionSpec(<your changeset here>);

// actually pend the merge
workspace.Merge(sourceBranch, targetBranch, changesetToMerge, changesetToMerge);

// check in the merge
workspace.CheckIn(workspace.GetPendingChanges(), "your comment");
```