# Dynamic Workspace.Merge TFS changesets

Tags: c#, .net, tfs

I'm writing a TFS plugin to automate merging of changesets related to a work item whenever said work item is changed from state "Resolved" to state "Closed". The following code is what I have so far:

**C#**

```
private void Action_ResolvedToClosed()
{
    //Linq query for getting changesets associated with the current work item
    var changeSets = WorkItem.Links
        .OfType<ExternalLink>()
        .Select(link =>
            VersionControlServer.ArtifactProvider.GetChangeset(new Uri(link.LinkedArtifactUri))).ToList();

    if (!changeSets.Any())
    {
        LOG_NOCHANGESETS(WorkItem.Id);
        return;
    }

    Workspace workspace = VersionControlServer.GetWorkspace(<My Workspace>);

    var source = URI_LOCAL; // $/<Project Name>/<Working Branch>
    var destination = URI_DEV; // $/<Project Name>/<Development Branch>

    // Merge applicable changesets
    foreach (var versionSpec in changeSets.Select(changeset => new ChangesetVersionSpec(changeset.ChangesetId)))
    {
        workspace.Merge(source, destination, versionSpec, versionSpec);
        workspace.CheckIn(workspace.GetPendingChanges(), "**Automated Merge**");
        LOG_SUCCESS(versionSpec.ChangesetId, WorkItem.Id);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to dynamically generate the `workspace` variable? Odds are I won't be the one actually making changes - the goal is to automate this process for our devs.

**UPDATE:** I'm pretty sure what I'm looking for in this second part is [GetStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.getstatus%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so it can be ignored. The paragraph above is my real question.

*Secondary:* I feel like automating merges can't be [this simple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092854/how-to-merge-tfs-change-sets-programmatically/12110848#12110848). What happens if merge conflicts arise? Does `Workspace.Merge` fail gracefully? Are there any other glaring issues that someone with a bit more experience with the TFS API can point out?

Comment: What's your definition of *fail gracefully*?  It creates conflicts in your workspace...  it doesn't set your computer on fire...  so maybe?

Comment: I guess my definition of fail gracefully - in this context - would be to notify the user of conflicts, and maybe even deny the state change until conflicts are resolved. So really, the second question is: Does `Workspace.Merge` have an event I can listen for and act on?

Comment: tl;dr - fail gracefully == doesn't throw an exception that I'm not currently handling.

Comment: Great!  You won't be able to check in after that, but no exception will be thrown, which sounds about like what you want...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it sounds like you want to query the user's workspace cache to get the appropriate `Workspace` and "realize" it.  If

```
WorkspaceInfo workspaceInfo = Workstation.Current.GetLocalWorkspaceInfo(path);
Workspace workspace = workspaceInfo.GetWorkspace(new TfsTeamProjectCollection(workspaceInfo.ServerUri);
```

However, as you point out, you may prefer to create a temporary workspace.  This will ensure that you do not conflict with any changes the user is trying to make in their own workspace.  For example:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection"));
VersionControlServer vcs = tpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
Workspace workspace = vcs.CreateWorkspace("MERGE-TEMP");
workspace.Map("$/Merge-Source", @"C:\Temp\Merge\Source");
workspace.Map("$/Merge-Target", @"C:\Temp\Merge\Target");
```

Second, if you run into merge conflicts, they will be set in the workspace.  You can query the `NumConflicts` method of the returned [GetStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.getstatus.aspx).  (Though you will not be able to `Checkin` untli you have resolved the conflicts.

Comment: I actually just stumbled across the WorkspaceInfo class a few minutes ago! In your example, what is `path`? Is that just the local path that the dev should have the team project mapped to (something like: `C:\dev\MyTeamProject`)? Does this require the assumption that all devs have the same path mapping?

Comment: It should work for a server path as well, since the workspace cache is how you bootstrap the mappings.

Comment: since the plugin will ultimately run on a server (I'm testing locally atm), I should be able to use `http://localhost:8080/tfs` as the server path then right? My logs don't seem to like that: `TF10121: The path 'http://localhost:8080/tfs' is not found or not supported. Type or select a different path.`

Comment: So that's actually a server URI, not a server path.  When I say server path, I mean something that starts with `$/` and is then mapped to a local path.  But I'm mistaken - you'll need to use a local path for the workspace cache since - of course - you can map a server path multiple places on the same machine so it's ambiguous.

Comment: Is it possible that creating a temporary workspace is the right solution here?

Comment: @JordanForeman Yes, that probably makes a lot of sense, actually.

Comment: Cool. If you want to edit your answer to suggest that, I'll accept it. Thanks for all of your help!