# Programmatically Merging using TeamFoundationClient TFS2008 and VS2010

Tags: c#, tfs, merge

I have Addin VS (maybe in future VSIX) for VS 2010.
I want to do branch of any single files (sql files) and later do merge programmatically.

I have seen several options:

```
GetStatus status = workspace.Merge
```

[How to merge TFS change sets programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092854/how-to-merge-tfs-change-sets-programmatically)

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2009/04/20/tfs-api-part-19-merge/

```
MergeContent(Conflict, true);
```

workspace.Merge can show dialog modal for merge (diffmerge.exe I think) and show results (resolveing conflicts) ? Note: in my case, now, I want show merge tool.

[TFS API MergeContent returns false without showing merge tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160736/tfs-api-mergecontent-returns-false-without-showing-merge-tool)

There are tf commands (command line, not C##

> tf diff[erence] itemspec [/version:versionspec]
>
> tf merge [/recursive] [/force] [/candidate] [/discard]
>   [/version:versionspec] [/lock:none|checkin|checkout] [/preview]
>   [/baseless] [/nosummary]  [/noimplicitbaseless] [/conservative]
>   [/format:(brief|detailed)] [/noprompt] [/login:username,[password]]
>   source destination
>
> tf resolve [itemspec]
>
> [/auto:(AutoMerge|TakeTheirs|KeepYours|
>
> OverwriteLocal|DeleteConflict
>
> |KeepYoursRenameTheirs)]
>
> [/preview] [(/overridetype:overridetype | /converttotype:converttype]
>   [/recursive]
>
> [/newname:path] [/noprompt]
>
> [/login:username, [password]]

any suggestions for do merging of files, and have to options:

1) show dialog for merging (diffmerge)

2) auto, without show dialog for merging (diffmerge or another?) and resolving conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

copy vsDiffMerge.exe from visual studio installation dir C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE inside App Exe file

```
var mergetool = new ThirdPartyToolDefinition(".*",ToolOperations.Merge,"vsDiffMerge.exe","","/m %1 %2 %3 %4");
var toolcol= ThirdPartyToolDefinitionCollection.Instance.FindTool(".*",ToolOperations.Merge);
if (toolcol == null)
   {
   ThirdPartyToolDefinitionCollection.Instance.AddTool(mergetool);
   ThirdPartyToolDefinitionCollection.Instance.PersistAllToRegistry();
   }

var controlsAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ControlAddItemsExclude));
var vcResolveCoinflictsDialogType = controlsAssembly.GetType("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls.DialogResolveConflicts");
var ci = vcResolveCoinflictsDialogType.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null, new[] { typeof(Workspace), typeof(string[]), typeof(bool) }, null);
var resolveCoinflictsDialog = (Form)ci.Invoke(new object[] { workspace, null, true });
resolveCoinflictsDialog.ShowDialog(parent);

ThirdPartyToolDefinitionCollection.Instance.Remove(mergetool);
ThirdPartyToolDefinitionCollection.Instance.PersistAllToRegistry();
```