# when i open TFS Resolve Conflicts dialog with reflection Merge Change in Merge Tool not working

Tags: tfs, merge-conflict-resolution

when i open TFS resolve conflicts dialog with reflection Merge Changes in Merge Tool not working and i get this error (TF10201) but with TF command working

```
public void resolveConf(string workspaceName, IWin32Window parent)
    {

        var workspace = VersionControlServer.GetWorkspace(workspaceName, ".");

        var controlsAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ControlAddItemsExclude));
        var vcResolveCoinflictsDialogType = controlsAssembly.GetType("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls.DialogResolveConflicts");
        var ci = vcResolveCoinflictsDialogType.GetConstructor(
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public,
            null,
            new[] { typeof(Workspace), typeof(string[]), typeof(bool) },
            null);
        var resolveCoinflictsDialog = (Form)ci.Invoke(new object[] { workspace, null, true });
        resolveCoinflictsDialog.ShowDialog(parent);
    }
```

Comment: What's the detail error message of TF10201 did you get ? And only just the "merge changes" feature in merge tool not working?

Comment: i solve problem thanks for your commnet https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27194811/programmatically-merging-using-teamfoundationclient-tfs2008-and-vs2010?rq=1